# Error with Client Web Service Soap

Tags: php, web, soap, service, wsdl

I have my web service which I am sure is good because I have been using almost the same code for another project.

```
<?php

try
{

    $input=$_POST['txtInput'];
    $wsdl='http://localhost/Search.wsdl';
    $options=array('cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,'features'=>SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);


    echo "hi1";

    $client=new SoapClient($wsdl,$options);
    echo "hi2";

    $response=$client->viewHealth($input);
    echo "hi3";
    if(isset($response->Health))
    {

        $HTMLDocument="<!Doctype html>
        <html>
         <head>
          <title>Health</title>
          <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'/>
         </head>
         <body>

           <table border='2'>
            <thead>
             <tr id='tabs'>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Symptoms</th>
              <th>Treatments</th>
             </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>";
        foreach($response->Health as $record)
        {
            $HTMLDocument.="<tr><td>".$record->Title."</td>";
            $HTMLDocument.="<td>".$record->Description."</td>";
            $HTMLDocument.="<td>".$record->Symptoms."</td>";
            $HTMLDocument.="<td>".$record->Treatments."</td></tr>";
        }
        $HTMLDocument.="</tbody></table></body></html>";
        echo $HTMLDocument;
    }
    else
    { }

}
```

It is echoing hi1, but not echoing hi2, hi3. I have no idea what is wrong. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Add a

```
catch (Exception $e) {
 echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

After your try{} to see what exception is thrown. I would assume that the wsdl is not reachable.

Comment: I have already placed one there. But a blank page is being displayed.

Comment: I am getting an Internal Server Error Exception

Comment: I have tried debugging but now I'm getting Exception:looks like we got no XML document